# Custom Property Value Converter Umbraco Returns Empty

Tags: c#, razor, umbraco, umbraco7, razor-2

this is my code

```
@inherits Umbraco.Web.Mvc.UmbracoTemplatePage<ContentModels.HomePage>
@using ContentModels = Umbraco.Web.PublishedContentModels;
@using System.Web.Script.Serialization;
@using Newtonsoft.Json.Linq;
@using System.Collections.Generic;
@using Umbraco.Core.Models.PublishedContent;
@using Umbraco.Core.PropertyEditors;
@using Newtonsoft.Json;
@using System.Linq;


@{
  Layout = "Master1.cshtml";
}


     <!-- Top menu -->
        @*@Html.Partial("TopMenu")*@
        <!-- End top menu -->
        <!-- Main nav -->
        @Html.Partial("MainMenu")
        <!-- Main nav ends -->

@Html.Partial("PromoCarousel")  

<div class="landing-page">
  @CurrentPage.GetGridHtml("bodyText")
</div>
<div class="col-lg-12">
   @Umbraco.Field("promo")
</div>




@{

    if (CurrentPage.HasValue("promo"))
    {
        var promoListValue = CurrentPage.GetPropertyValue("promo");



   var serializer = new JavaScriptSerializer();
     string json =  serializer.Serialize(promoListValue);
      var testmodel  = serializer.DeserializeObject(json);


     @* foreach (var item in promoListValue)
            {
                <span>@item </span>
            }  

           @Html.Raw(json) 
            @Html.Raw(Json.Encode(json))
            *@
             @Html.Raw(testmodel)

            var obj = Model.Content.GetPropertyValue<MyLookAlikeArchetypeModel>("promo");
            <span>@obj </span>
             foreach(var item in obj)
                {
                    <p>@item.img</p>
                    <p>@item.alias</p>
                }

    } 



}



<div class="container _borderless landingpage">

</div>
@functions {



public class MyLookAlikeArchetypeFieldSet
{
    [JsonProperty("alias")]
    public string alias { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("img")]
    public string img { get; set; }
}

public class MyLookAlikeArchetypeModel
{
    private List<MyLookAlikeArchetypeFieldSet> _Items;

    public MyLookAlikeArchetypeModel()
    {
        _Items = new List<MyLookAlikeArchetypeFieldSet>();
    }

    public MyLookAlikeArchetypeModel(List<MyLookAlikeArchetypeFieldSet> list)
    {
        _Items = list;
    }

    public IEnumerator<MyLookAlikeArchetypeFieldSet> GetEnumerator()
    {
        return _Items.GetEnumerator();
    }

    public bool Any()
    {
        return _Items.Any();
    }
}

public class MyLookAlikeArchetypeModelPropertyConverter : IPropertyValueConverter
{
    public object ConvertDataToSource(PublishedPropertyType propertyType, object source, bool preview)
    {
        return source;
    }

    public object ConvertSourceToObject(PublishedPropertyType propertyType, object source, bool preview)
    {
        try
        {
            var list = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<MyLookAlikeArchetypeFieldSet>>(source as string);
            return new MyLookAlikeArchetypeModel(list);
        }
        catch
        {
            return new MyLookAlikeArchetypeModel();
        }
    }

    public object ConvertSourceToXPath(PublishedPropertyType propertyType, object source, bool preview)
    {
        return null;
    }

    public bool IsConverter(PublishedPropertyType propertyType)
    {
        return propertyType.PropertyEditorAlias.Equals("My.Plugin.Package.Manifest.Alias");
    }
}
}
```

but the obj returning as empty

```
 var obj = Model.Content.GetPropertyValue<MyLookAlikeArchetypeModel>("promo");
```

the response for `CurrentPage.GetPropertyValue("promo");`

```
 [ { "alias": "1", "content": "1", "img": "/media/1069/509253678.jpg" }, { "alias": "Slide 2", "content": "2", "img": "/media/1074/636609180.jpg" } ]
```

any help will be appreciated

Comment: Yry to move your "@functions definitions" inside a file.cs (inside the folder App_Code if you don't want to compile it)

Comment: Have you tried sticking some breakpoints or logging into the `IsConverter` and `ConvertSourceToObject` methods? It would be great to first confirm that your property value converter is even being picked up as a PropertyValueConverter in umbraco.

There is also a `PropertyValueConverterBase` that you can inherit from. It, in turn, inherits from the `IPropertyValueConverter` interface and does nothing else but implement the interface with some default, virtual methods that you can override. This won't solve your problem but I like it better than inheriting straight from the interface.

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you just deserialise it.

something like this... (sorry not tested this)

```
        var object = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<MyLookAlikeArchetypeModel> (archetypeValueAsString);

        foreach (var item in object)
        {
            var Img = item.GetValue<string>("img");
        }
```